# How to implement elaborate functions in a JNI project

Tags: android, c, java-native-interface, linux-device-driver, native

Hi I am trying to implement the following native code in a JNI project, and I am a couple of questions. 
Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
/* Our file descriptor */
int fd;
int rc = 0;
char *rd_buf[16];
printf("%s: entered\n", argv[0]);
/* Open the device */
fd = open("/dev/hello1", O_RDWR);
if ( fd == -1 ) {
perror("open failed");
rc = fd;
exit(-1);
}
printf("%s: open: successful\n", argv[0]);
/* Issue a read */
rc = read(fd, rd_buf, 0);
if ( rc == -1 ) {
perror("read failed");
close(fd);
exit(-1);
}
printf("%s: read: returning %d bytes!\n", argv[0], rc);
close(fd);
return 0;
}
```

My questions are: 
1- How do i handle argv and argc? I assume most of this code goes in a C file in my JNI directory.

2- How do I handle functions with structures as parameters passed to them? That is, not just functions with basic type parameters like int, boolean, String, etc.? How do I implement the Android/java version of these structures in my MainActivity so that when I run javah, I get the corresponding native method? So if I have a function that uses the following as a parameter:

```
struct tbt_registered_listener_list {
    struct list_head                 list;
    struct tbt_register_listener_req svc;
    u8  *sb_reg;
    int                        rcv_req_flag;
};
```

What is the corresponding Java version of this, that goes in the Android Main Activity please? Do I have to create a class with the same parameters in my Android Main Activity, and then run javah?

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't.  You wouldn't make a main function like this at all.  That's how command line programs work.  Instead you should encapsulate what you need as a normal C function with standard parameters.  Directly converting it like this is doable (use an array of strings), but would be really bad and really inefficient code.

Comment: Is there a better alternative for interfacing with a device driver from the APK?

Comment: Its not the JNI that I'm objecting to.  JNI is fine, in the right places.  But you wouldn't directly call a main function like that.  Instead you'd write a function that does exactly what's needed.  Since you require 1 string parameter, it would take 1 string parameter, rather than having an argc and argv at all.  JNI doesn't use a main function.

Comment: Ok. I'll deal with argv and ... I appreciate your comment. I so hope someone can give me some pseudo code for what goes in the MainActivity for a non-standard function, and how I can call it from the JNI file.

Comment: I was referring to MainActivity on the Andorid side. I really appreciate your comment though. I got what you meant about the native main(). No problem; I'll figure something.

Comment: On the Java side, just declare the function as native Foo(params).  Then the matching C function should be my_full_package_and_class_Foo(params).  Then calling the java function will automatically link to the C one

Comment: Oh. I got what you meant. It only takes one type definition, which occurs in the native code. What is on the Android side is just a placeholder. Got it. Thanks.

Comment: To whoever voted the question down. I have read a number of JNI tutorials; the oracle's design document. None discussed JNI implementation for anything other than a simple string. So I am not sure what research could have been done on it. I appreciate if you could elaborate.